# Which part of my AWS EKS setup isn't running correctly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pod, aws-application-load-balancer

I have setup an EKS cluster and configured it to run 6 or so different microservices in their own pods. I am using an ALB as the ingress to said pods and have noticed that sometimes the connection to the pods will time out. I am struggling to determine exactly what the cause of this is.

The pods work as expected for the first X amount of requests but once they have been left for a while and then I try to make a new request, the connection will time out. Could this be due to the ALB or am I missing something with Kubernetes?

One of the deployments looks like this:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: challengepasswordlookupservice
  labels:
    app: challengepasswordlookupservice
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: challengepasswordlookupservice
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: challengepasswordlookupservice
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: challengepasswordlookupservice
          image: *withheld*
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80

---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: challengepasswordlookupservice
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: challengepasswordlookupservice
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

And the ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: golf-high-service-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig":{ "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:eu-west-2:206106816545:certificate/8d91b886-9d57-4fcf-b016-04959cf4d97d
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes: idle_timeout.timeout_seconds=60
spec:
  rules:
    - host: "*withheld*"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: "/*"
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
                service:
                  name: ssl-redirect
                  port:
                    name: use-annotation
          - path: "/*"
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
                service:
                  name: challengepasswordlookupservice
                  port:
                    number: 80
```

Comment: hi and welcome to stackoverflow. please add more information to your question. e.g. logfiles, kubernetes resource definition files, etc. without additional information the community is not able to help you

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the `idle_timeout.timeout_seconds=60` to something relevant like maybe 1800 inside the annotations and then try it out.

I believe you'll want the load-balancer-attributes annotation set to `idle_timeout.timeout_seconds=1800`

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/blob/8c2fbfd478a77f983afde2bb5a3ce2f06957e75d/internal/alb/lb/attributes.go#L20

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the ALB. On AWS, an ALB requires 1 subnet in at least two different availability zones. One of the subnets that was attached did not have an internet gateway attached and thus was not establishing a connection when the request was routed to this subnet.